# Lights go out in part of the house whenever I plug.something in

Tags: electrical, shutoff

Weird thing. Whenever I plug something (*TV,computer, anything really besides the fridge which is even weirder*)  in in one part of the house a bzt bzt sounds can be heard, lights flicker and electricity goes off in that one part for several minutes.

No safety goes off. Lights flicker several times during those few minutes until electricity comes back.

I will call an electrician, but any idea to what might be the cause?

Comment: What model breaker panel do you have?

Comment: Conversation with My doctor:   **Me**; It hurts when i pull my finger. **Doctor**; Dont pull you finger. -- Dont plug "something in"

Comment: This sounds like a **DANGEROUS SITUATION**. Get it looked at **ASAP**. You may even want to **TURN OFF POWER TO THE ENTIRE HOUSE** before you do so. You could get a fire, you could get a death; no way of telling.

Comment: Do you know what part of the house that is? Have you figured out which circuits in your panel that part of the house is on?

Comment: I am living in rent so I have to depend on the house owner.. I will insist on getting an electrician to check it out. I would rather avoid having expensive electronics and maybe ME getting burned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably a broken wire or bad connection in the box behind the outlet where you plugged in.  I recommend getting an electrician to look at it RIGHT NOW.  You could cause a fire in the wall and burn your house down.

Comment: Yeah, this is what happened. One of the problems. The other one was that there was some slightly cut wire surrounded by some wallpaper. Electrician said it's quite amazing we didn't get a fire. Yikes.

Answer (score 2):

If it's knocking out your whole house like that (multiple circuits, right?) you may have a service wire problem which would be the bailiwick of the power company.

I don't know if you own a voltmeter or a Kill-a-Watt power monitor, but it would be good to check the voltages on your various circuits.  If some are below 120V that is one thing... but if any are *above* 120V, that is most likely a "Lost Neutral".   The bare wire carrying the other wires from the pole is the neutral, being the heavy lifter it's been known to break off.  Don't attempt to use power during a lost-neutral situation, you'll fry half your appliances if you try.